# How can I use bunde only in require-dev?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, require

I made a `composer diagnose` and got the following error message:

> WARNING symfony/monolog-bundle is required both in require and
>   require-dev, this can lead to unexpected behavior
>   require.symfony/serializer-pack : unbound version constraints (*)
>   should be avoided require.symfony/webpack-encore-pack : unbound
>   version constraints (*) should be avoided

How can I use monolog-bundle only in require-dev?

Comment: Did you tried to remove it from `require` section in your `composer.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerun `composer require symfony/monolog-bundle --dev` that should fix your issue.

Another way would be to edit your composer.json and remove the package out of the section `require` but keeping it in the section `require-dev`